# Django - Apache2 Internal Server Error

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu, apache2, mod-wsgi

I created a django project under `/home/toto/Desktop` named `dash_test` and I wanted to serve my Django application with Apache2 and mod_wsgi.

I installed the Apache web server, the mod_wsgi, and pip using this command `sudo apt-get install python-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi`. And I created a python virtual environment within the project directory named `developer`.

The allowed_hosts in the `settings.py` looks like this :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']`
```

I added the static_url and the static_root:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

I did run a `collectstatic`

And I configured `apache` by editing the `000-default.conf` :

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static /home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/static
    <Directory /home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/dash_test>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess dash_test python-home=/home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/developer python-path=/home/toto/Desktop/dash_test
    WSGIProcessGroup dash_test
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/dash_test/wsgi.py
 </VirtualHost>
```

when I try to access the localhost I get this error:

> Internal Server Error
>     The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>     Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>     More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Here is the content of the apache2 `error.log`:

```
[Thu Jun 14 13:25:48.134132 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21611] [remote 127.0.0.1:15106] mod_wsgi (pid=21611): Target WSGI script '/home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/dash_test/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jun 14 13:25:48.134152 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21611] [remote 127.0.0.1:15106] mod_wsgi (pid=21611): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/dash_test/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jun 14 13:25:48.134167 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21611] [remote 127.0.0.1:15106] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 14 13:25:48.134182 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21611] [remote 127.0.0.1:15106]   File "/home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/dash_test/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
[Thu Jun 14 13:25:48.134203 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21611] [remote 127.0.0.1:15106]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jun 14 13:25:48.134216 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 21611] [remote 127.0.0.1:15106] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

I am using MySQL and phpMyAdmin instead of db.sqlite3

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try run `sudo chmod -R 777 /home/toto/Desktop/dash_test` and reload apache

Comment: Thank you I did run the command but I still have the same error

Comment: Did you reload Apache after editing the config?

Comment: yes I did /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
<Directory /home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/dash_test>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

use:

```
<Directory /home/toto/Desktop/dash_test>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

You were using the wrong directory.

That or you have:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/wsgi.py
```

wrong and it is meant to be:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/dash_test/wsgi.py
```

The location of the `wsgi.py` doesn't actually look quite right if this is a Django app.

What is the actual path to the `wsgi.py` file.

The directory argument above should be the directory it is in.

Comment: The actual path to the wsgi.py file is:  /home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/dash_test/wsgi.py

Comment: I did change the path in the WSGIScriptAlias but I still have the same error

Comment: I edited my question because after relaoding the server I get 500 internal server error

Comment: What is ``/home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/developer``. Because you have set ``python-home`` to that, is expected that that is a Python virtual environment and so Django must be installed in it. Is that really the root directory of the Python virtual environment. Run, ``python`` from your virtual environment and see what ``import sys; sys.prefix`` gives you. That directory it gives should be what ``python-home`` is set to. Details in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: yes it's a virtual environment. This is what I get when I run the 2 commands: >>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'/home/toto/Desktop/dash_test/developer'

Comment: And while running ``python`` from the virtual environment, if you go ``import django; django.__file__`` what do you get?

Comment: You're right I forgot to install django on it. I did now and it seems it's installed correctly. Thank you so much for your help I didn't know how it skipped my attention. now I got my app pages on the localhost. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I use Django 3.x and Apache 2.4 for upload my project in local host,indeed I going to test my project and Apache but I faced with same problem and when I check my Apache error.log it was : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'"

And config file seems ok and when I check it with :"sudo apache2ctl configtest"

But I use this 2 commands for solve the problem

```
  sudo a2dissite 000-default
  sudo a2ensite 000-default
```

and
sudo systemctl reload apache2